# How to write time (local system time), in text file or in log file using a Python script?

Tags: python, sikuli

I have to write a test case, for that I am using sikuli which works on a Python script,
here I am not able to write local system time in text file.

```
import time;

localtime = time.localtime(time.time())
inp=file("C:\\Users\\%path%\\Log.txt", 'w')
inp.write('************** Full Process ****************\n')
inp.write('Local current time :', localtime)  incorrect
```

Here I am creating a .txt file and also I have to write time 
and I don't know how to write the code.

Answer (score 5):

That's pretty much correct, but you have an error writing the time:

```
inp.write('Local current time :', localtime)
```

If you want to format a string like that, you need to use the `%` operator:

```
inp.write('Local current time : %s' % localtime)
```

Furthermore, just printing the Time object will print a very weird string. You want to write the date in a more convenient way, by example YYYY/MM/DD - HH:MM:SS. You do it like this:

```
localtime.strftime ('%Y/%m/%d - %H:%M:%S')
```

So your piece of code will be:

```
import time

localtime = time.localtime(time.time())
timestring = time.strftime ('%Y/%m/%d - %H:%M:%S')
inp=file("Log.txt", 'w')
inp.write('************** Full Process ****************\n')
inp.write('Local current time : %s' % timestring)
```

Comment: but when I am trying to use same % timestring at different placesin same code, I dont know why/how timing are same for all events, time before 13 sec is equal to time after 13 sec, m talking about HH:MM:SS.

Comment: Of course it's the same. The value of that variable is set in this line: `localtime = time.localtime(time.time())`. If you want to get a new time, you must call `time.time()` again.